# Angular, Show/Load different Div content using combo box

Tags: html, angular

Is it possible to show/load different div using combo box? For example i have two Divs that contain different tables, I want to show only one table at a time, we can change what table we want to see from a combo box and click load button. Here is the snippet

```html
<div align="center">
  <Select>
    <option value="survey101" name="survey101" id="survey101">Survey101</option>
    <option value="Survey102" name="survey102" id="survey102">Survey102</option>
  </Select>
  <button>LOAD</button>
</div>

<div>
  <ul *ngFor="let items of survey101">
  </ul>
</div>

<div>
  <ul *ngFor="let items of survey102">
  </ul>
</div>
```

If it is possible can anyone help/show me how? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedSurvey">
    <option value="survey101">Survey101</option>
    <option value="survey102">Survey102</option>
</select>


<div *ngIf="selectedSurvey.survey101">
    <ul *ngFor="let items of survey101"></ul>
</div>

<div *ngIf="selectedSurvey.survey102">
    <ul *ngFor="let items of survey102"></ul>
</div>
```

You will need to add a variable called `selectedSurvey` in your component's TS.

```
private selectedSurvey: string = ""
```

Answer (score 1):

You should have **`[(ngModel)]`** set for both select boxes, and based on the **`(ngModelChange)`**  get the selected value.

Then use **`*ngIf="selected ==="survey101"`** embed the table1

in the **`*ngIf="selected ==="survey102"`** embed the table2